# How to read an sqlite database file in Java? (Package)

Tags: java, programming-languages

Okay i know i have to use the JDBC etc, but im not sure how to implement the jar into my code, i have a basic code to open the file etc, but how can i actually incorporate the sqlite jar alongside my java class file to be run anywhere?
So for example i have a folder with:
Test.class
new.db
sqlite.jar

In Test.class i  have the basic connection and imports:

```
Connection connection = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    Statement statement = null;

    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:new.db");
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT empname FROM employee");
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            System.out.println("EMPLOYEE NAME:"
                    + resultSet.getString("empname"));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {  
        try {
            resultSet.close();
            statement.close();
            connection.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

So how can i have this simple little script portable?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the sqlite.jar to you classpath:

```
java -cp .;./sqlite.jar Anima
```

This should work. If not - please show your error message.

---

**Edit**

tested and verified. Create/Have a folder with the following content:

```
./project
    Anima.class
    sqlite.jar
```

then `cd` to folder `project` and do a

```
java -cp .;./sqlite.jar Anima
```

It works as expected on my machine.

Comment: hmm i don't understand this :S
My file is only one java file, just Anima.class and it runs by itself. the jar is in the same folder.

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at Anima.main(Anima.java:28)

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at Anima.main(Anima.java:42)